# swift unable to compare date and time with current date

Tags: ios, swift

here the date from api that i get

```
dateTime = "2021-06-08 09:00"
```

function that i made for compare date

```
  func hideBtn () {
    guard let isodate = dateFormatter.date(from:dateTime) else { return }
    if isodate < currentDateTime{
        self.Btn.isHidden = true
        self.aBtn.isHidden = true
    }
    else {
        self.Btn.isHidden = false
        self.aBtn.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

current date time that i get -->. 2021-06-08 08:53:47 +0000

Comment: It's unclear what's your exact issue? Is the `dateFormatter` working with `dateTime` at all? Is `isodate` not nil? Is it a TimeZone issue? How is set `dateFormatter`? Could you print `isodate` and `currentDateTime` to be sure? Is the correct if/else correctly called? Is `Btn` & `aBtn` correctly placed/connected? Not an wrong instance?

Comment: You need to return interval or date or you just need to compare the dates or what?